# Unable to view the screenshots in extent reports In Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-extent-report

We are able to view the screenshots locally. When we run the job in Jenkins we are unable to view the screenshots in extent reports. We are using extent reports v2.41.2. Both the screenshot and report are in the same directory. Kindly give us a solution in order to solve it.

```
       public static String takescreenshot(WebDriver driver, String Screenshotname) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMdd_yyyy_hh_mmaa").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            String dest = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ATOM_20Report\\"+Screenshotname + "_" + timeStamp + ".png";
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(dest));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Failed to take screenshot: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return dest;
}
public static void passTestwithsc(String Screenshotname, WebDriver driver) {

    Assert.assertTrue(true);
    String path = null;
    try {
        path = Helper.takescreenshot(driver, Screenshotname);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, logger.getDescription(),logger.addScreenCapture(path));

}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error that you see in the console when you try to access the screenshot.

Comment: I couldn't find any error in console I could see the extent report but screenshots aren't Getting displayed in Jenkins.When I see report locally I could see the screenshot in it but not jenkins.

Comment: Can you please share your method of capturing screenshot.

Comment: i have added the method of capturing screenshot

Comment: Jenkins is also running in your local system?

Comment: Hi everyone we solved the issue using Base64 Screenshot hence we are able to view the screenshot in extent report both in local as well as jenkins

Comment: kaviarasan: Congrats! have same problem as of yours. Can u please share your code snippet here?